# Finding Points within Polygon delivering erroneous results

Tags: sql, gis, tableau-api, postgis

I've used Tableau to display maps here (see Licenses Map tab): https://poursafe.com/los-angeles-city.

If you'll unselect the 'All' in the Council District filter on the right and select only district '14'. Then notice when adding district '9' all of the points from 9 falling within district 14?

My problem here is I don't know what the problem is so I can define it better. The points are the right lat/lon with SRID 4326. The Council Districts were SRID 2229 which I converted to 4326 using:

```
ALTER TABLE poursafe.ca_licenses
        ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point,4326) USING ST_Transform(geom,4326);
```

I then looked for any points within the council districts with:

```
UPDATE poursafe.ca_licenses dst
SET prem_council = district
FROM public.ca_la_la_council src
WHERE st_within(dst.geom,src.geom) AND dst.geom&&src.geom;
```

I cannot see any patterns when comparing other districts. Other problematic districts include at least 4 and 2.

Any help identifying the problem or solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Most of the point from 9 are in 9 . Around 1/3 is in 14, but exactly same is for points from 14 falling into 1.
Is ca_la_la_council geom is also 4326 or other SRID

Comment: Thanks for your help Grzegorz. I dumped the council district table and started over and it appears where I went wrong was mixing up Point vs. MultiPolygon  - the shape file was MultiPolygon and I was making ALTER statements as if the geom column were a POINT column.